# How do I retrieve the names of functions used in an .m file in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Say I have the following MATLAB function do_this.m

```
function result = do_this(input1, input2)
% input1 and input2 must have the same size.
    A = input1 + diag(input2);
    result = rand(size(input1)) + A;
end
```

I would like to know how to return an array of all the functions used in a given .m file. For example,

```
>> func_names = get_func_names('do_this.m')
```

So that `func_names` is `['diag', 'rand', 'size']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this sort of information from `depfun()`.

```
% See depfun helpfile
[TRACE_LIST, BUILTINS] = depfun('do_this.m');
```

`BUILTINS` is a cell array of all built-in functions needed by your function, and returns something like

```
BUILTINS = 

'colon'
'datenummx'
'diag'
'evalin'
'horzcat'
'loadobj'
'numel'
'plus'
'rand'
'saveobj'
'size'
'subsindex'
'subsref'
'vertcat'
```

Note that this also returns functions used by `diag()`, `rand()`, etc.

In R2014a (and up?), MATLAB warns `Warning: DEPFUN will be removed in a future release. Use matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts instead.` However, the suggested function does not return built-in functions, only user-defined ones.

Comment: BTW: R2014a warns: `Warning: DEPFUN will be removed in a future release. Use matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts instead.`.

Comment: Good to know, I'll update the answer once I get to a machine w/ R2014a+.

Comment: No need to wait: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.codetools.requiredfilesandproducts.html ;-)

Comment: But that only returns "user-authored" files, and OP wants to include built-in ones.

Comment: Ok. Didn't know about either of those functions until now. I just meant you could add the info to your answer.

Comment: Same! I didn't know if you meant they had the same functionality.